# How to get rid of strange transition moving in chrome when resizing the browser?

Tags: html, css, zooming, transition

We're developing a website with a lot of transition. In Firefox when you zoom in and out all is resizing static and without moving element, but when you resize in Chrome evering is moving out of place and gets bigger.

[>>Website<<](http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/)

How could I solve this transition problem in Chrome? I'm wondering if there is a fix.

A part of  my css code with transition:

```
#login{
float:right;
width:130px;
height:30px;
background:#7eb055;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 1s;
-o-transition: width 0.5s, height 1s;
-moz-transition: width 0.5s, height 1s;
-ms-transition: width 0.5s, height 1s;
transition: width 0.7s, height 1s;
}
```

Note that I tried `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` but this won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several li's inside an ul.

When you zoom, the ul resizes and so do the li's. But the li's have a transition on the resize, and then for some time they don't match anymore.

You have now

```
#main_nav_home li {
    /*   ....   */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

ul#main_nav_home{ 
    width:800px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

I would change the later to

```
#main_nav_home{ 
    width:800px;
    margin:0px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

Besides setting the transition, I have removed the element type, sine you are not going to repeat the id.

or, even better:

```
#main_nav_home, #main_nav_home li { 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

This way you are fool-proofing future changes in the timing of the transition.

Comment: It still moves but it's way better now. :) Thanks.